# Can you programmatically disable a plugin in Gradle that has previously been enabled

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

We have a corporate build system running on docker that hard codes the applying of the gradle Java plugin inside init.gradle.

This causes problems for us as we want to use the java-platform plugin to build a BOM artefact, and you can't have both the java and the java-platform plugin enabled at once.

As a stop gap solution, is it possible to dynamically unload/disable a previously loaded plugin by calling code in build.gradle.kts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot disable an already applied plugin. Gradle doesn't provide any way to do that. And I think that this ability will not appear in the near future.

If you look at the `apply` method of the [Java Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugin-development/src/main/java/org/gradle/plugin/devel/plugins/JavaGradlePluginPlugin.java#L139) you will see that the plugin does a lot of things. It seems that everything can no longer be rolled back.

[A feature-suggestion](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/19248) to add the ability to "rollback" an already applied plugin has been opened since 2021 without any activity.